# Pandas - Create a column based on values from 2 other columns

Tags: python, pandas

I am trying to tackle something on Pandas but I am not sure where to start.

I have a dataframe with multiple columns, but the ones of interest for this question look like this:

```
df = pd.DataFrame(data = {'subject': [1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 3, 3, 3], 'val': [np.nan, 2, np.nan, np.nan, np.nan, 7, np.nan, np.nan, 10]})

    subject    val
0        1     NaN
1        1     2.0
2        1     NaN
3        2     NaN
4        2     NaN
5        2     7.0
6        3     NaN
7        3     NaN
8        3    10.0
```

I want to create a third column which, for each subject, has the value on column val for the corresponding subject:

```
   subject    val  total
0        1     NaN   2
1        1     2.0   2
2        1     NaN   2
3        2     NaN   7
4        2     NaN   7
5        2     7.0   7
6        3     NaN  10
7        3     NaN  10
8        3    10.0  10
```

I know I can do

```
df[['subject', 'val']].dropna()
```

to get the values for the third column, but that would lose all the other columns in the dataframe (which has different values in each row).

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By using `ffill` and `bfill`

```
df['New']=df.groupby('subject').val.apply(lambda x : x.ffill().bfill())
df
Out[257]: 
   subject   val   New
0        1   NaN   2.0
1        1   2.0   2.0
2        1   NaN   2.0
3        2   NaN   7.0
4        2   NaN   7.0
5        2   7.0   7.0
6        3   NaN  10.0
7        3   NaN  10.0
8        3  10.0  10.0
```

Answer (score 1):

try this,

```
df['total'] =df.groupby('subject')['val'].transform('sum')
```

or

```
df['total2'] =df.groupby('subject')['val'].transform(lambda x:x[x.notnull()].unique()) #this will remove NaN records and give you unique element in each group
```

Output:

```
   subject   val  total  total2
0        1   NaN    2.0     2.0
1        1   2.0    2.0     2.0
2        1   NaN    2.0     2.0
3        2   NaN    7.0     7.0
4        2   NaN    7.0     7.0
5        2   7.0    7.0     7.0
6        3   NaN   10.0    10.0
7        3   NaN   10.0    10.0
8        3  10.0   10.0    10.0
```

Comment: Thanks! That did work, except that sometimes I have the value on column 'val' repeated (for example, 2 rows in the same subject have value X, instead of only 1 having a value). Is there another option in the transform function I can use?

Comment: @user5576 - added to the solution please take a look